# Formastic Bootstrap Rails Error- No Such File to Load ButtonsHelpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

I'm completely stuck on this error. Using Rails 3.1 trying to implement Formastic Bootstrap gem and getting error:

**`': no such file to load -- formtastic/helpers/buttons_helper (LoadError)**

**Application.css**

```
*= require formtastic
*= require formtastic-bootstrap
```

**Gemfile**

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass'
end
```

**formastic.rb**

```
Formtastic::Helpers::FormHelper.builder = FormtasticBootstrap::FormBuilder

gem 'formtastic'

gem 'formtastic-bootstrap'
```

**buttons_helper**

```
module FormtasticBootstrap
  module Helpers
    module ButtonsHelper

      include Formtastic::Helpers::ButtonsHelper

      def buttons(*args, &block)

        html_options = args.extract_options!
        html_options[:class] ||= "actions"

        if html_options.has_key?(:name)
          ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn('The :name option is not supported')
        end

        if block_given?
          template.content_tag(:div, html_options) do
            yield
          end          
        else
          args = [:commit] if args.empty?
          contents = args.map { |button_name| send(:"#{button_name}_button") }
          template.content_tag(:div, html_options.except(:builder, :parent, :name)) do
            Formtastic::Util.html_safe(contents.join)
          end
        end

      end

      def commit_button(*args)
        options = args.extract_options!
        text = options.delete(:label) || args.shift

        text = (localized_string(commit_button_i18n_key, text, :action, :model => commit_button_object_name) ||
                Formtastic::I18n.t(commit_button_i18n_key, :model => commit_button_object_name)) unless text.is_a?(::String)

        button_html = options.delete(:button_html) || {}
        button_html.merge!(:class => [button_html[:class], "btn commit", commit_button_i18n_key].compact.join(' '))

        # TODO We don't have a wrapper. Add deprecation message.
        # wrapper_html = options.delete(:wrapper_html) || {}
        # wrapper_html[:class] = (commit_button_wrapper_html_class << wrapper_html[:class]).flatten.compact.join(' ')

        accesskey = (options.delete(:accesskey) || default_commit_button_accesskey) unless button_html.has_key?(:accesskey)
        button_html = button_html.merge(:accesskey => accesskey) if accesskey

        Formtastic::Util.html_safe(submit(text, button_html))
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had same issue. Apparently latest release of formtastic 2.2.0 (pushed yesterday) is not compatible with formtastic-bootstrap

For that you have to specify earlier version of formtastic

Just add following line above `gem 'formtastic-bootstrap'`

```
gem 'formtastic', " ~> 2.1.1"
```

it is little earlier version of formtastic.