# formtastic-bootstrap installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

I just installed the formatastic-bootstrap gem for Ruby on Rails and Twitter Bootstrap. Per the readme file, I added  `*= require formtastic-bootstrap` to application.css, I created a file called `config/initializers/formtastic.rb` whose contents are `Formtastic::Helpers::FormHelper.builder = FormtasticBootstrap::FormBuilder`, and I ran bundle install. When I try to start my rails server now, I get the following error.

> /Users/wrightgd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/formtastic-bootstrap-1.1.1/lib/formtastic-bootstrap/helpers/buttons_helper.rb:5:in
>   `': cannot load such file --
>   formtastic/helpers/buttons_helper (LoadError)

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098801/formastic-bootstrap-rails-error-no-such-file-to-load-buttonshelpers) latest version of formtastic is not compatible with formtastic-bootstrap. Try older version `gem 'formtastic', " ~> 2.1.1"`

Comment: Support for 2.2 is about 30 days away.