# Formtastic Gem issues with Rails 4 upgrade

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, formtastic, ruby-on-rails-4.2

While upgrading an application from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.2.8, ruby version has remained the same at 2.3.2. Bundle install and bundle update are running successfully with no warnings or errors.

**Environment:** windows, ruby 2.3.2

Performing any rake tasks or starting of server breaks, find the errors below,

Rake task breaks:

```
  Error:[rake --tasks] C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/ast/feature_element.rb:52: warning: circular argument reference - name
  rake aborted!
  LoadError: cannot load such file -- formtastic/helpers/buttons_helper
  C:/workspace/project1/lib/ext/gems/formtastic/formtastic.rb:13:in `<module:Formtastic>'
  C:/workspace/project1/lib/ext/gems/formtastic/formtastic.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
  C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
```

Development Server start throws error:

```
C:/workspace/project1/lib/ext/gems/formtastic/formtastic.rb:13:in `<module:Formtastic>': cannot load such file -- formtastic/helpers/buttons_helper (LoadError)
  from C:/workspace/projects/CosmoD2Upgrade/director2/lib/ext/gems/formtastic/formtastic.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
```

Gemfile:

```
   # form builder
   gem 'formtastic'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
formtastic (3.1.5)
  actionpack (>= 3.2.13)
```

I have tried multiple versions of Formtastic gem which could not resolve the issue even going down to 2.0 version. Let me know if any patches or fixes around this is available.

**Update**: Including the error stack trace of rake failure

```
Error:[rake --tasks] C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/ast/feature_element.rb:52: warning: circular argument reference - name
    rake aborted!
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- formtastic/helpers/buttons_helper
    C:/workspace/project/lib/ext/gems/formtastic/formtastic.rb:13:in `<module:Formtastic>'
    C:/workspace/project/lib/ext/gems/formtastic/formtastic.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    C:/workspace/project/config/application.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
    C:/workspace/project/config/application.rb:9:in `each'
    C:/workspace/project/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/workspace/project/Rakefile:4:in `require'
    C:/workspace/project2/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
    C:/workspace/project/bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
    Polyglot::PolyglotLoadError: Failed to load C:/workspace/project/lib/ext/gems/formtastic/formtastic.rb using extensions rb, treetop, tt
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:55:in `load'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:68:in `rescue in require'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    C:/workspace/project/config/application.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
    C:/workspace/project/config/application.rb:9:in `each'
    C:/workspace/project/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/workspace/project/Rakefile:4:in `require'
    C:/workspace/project/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
    C:/workspace/projects/bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
```

The error points to the below file and the buttonhelper call.

```
    .....  
    Line no 13:
    module Helpers::ButtonsHelper
      def commit_button(*args)
        options = args.extract_options!
        text = options.delete(:label) || args.shift

        text = (localized_string(commit_button_i18n_key, text, :action, :model => commit_button_object_name) ||
            Formtastic::I18n.t(commit_button_i18n_key, :model => commit_button_object_name)) unless text.is_a?(::String)

        button_html = options.delete(:button_html) || {}
        button_html.merge!(:class => [button_html[:class], commit_button_i18n_key].compact.join(' '))

        wrapper_html = options.delete(:wrapper_html) || {}
        wrapper_html[:class] = (commit_button_wrapper_html_class << wrapper_html[:class]).flatten.compact.join(' ')

        accesskey = (options.delete(:accesskey) || default_commit_button_accesskey) unless button_html.has_key?(:accesskey)
        button_html = button_html.merge(:accesskey => accesskey) if accesskey

        Formtastic::Util.html_safe(submit(text, button_html))
      end
    end
    .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you use `formtastic` and the `formtastic-bootstrap` gem. Unfortunately `formtastic-bootstrap` is not compatible with current `formtastic` versions, furthermore it seems unmaintained, because it didn't receive any updates during the last two years.

I see two options:

1. Downgrade to `formtastic` `~> 2.1.1` like mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10110154/2483313).
2. Replace or fork and fix the `formtastic-bootstrap` to be able to move forwards.

I would choose the second option. Using an old software stack just because it depends on a gem (that seems to be abandoned anyway) doesn't sound like a good plan to me.

Comment: I had seen that answer but i'm not using formtastic-bootstrap gem. I'm using bootstrap after including the related files in my project folder. Gemfile.lock shows formtastic depends only on actionpack as i have mentioned in qsn.

Comment: The error message tells that you require `formtastic/helpers/buttons_helper` somewhere in your code (directly or in a gem). That module doesn't exist anymore in newer versions of `formtastic`. Please post the file in with you require that helper or name the gem that requires it (or post your Gemfile.lock).

Comment: i updated my qsn with error stack trace which points to the references. It's being called from formtastic.rb, i had seen deprecation message on github page too but wonder why the reference is still left in the gem code

Comment: My gemfile.lock is not having any references for formtastic except the gem itself and also not present under any gem as a form of dependency

Comment: Hmm, the error message doesn't point to the `formtastic` gem, but to this file: `C:/workspace/project1/lib/ext/gems/formtastic/formtastic.rb` that is in your apps `lib` folder. It seems like there is some code that extends `formtastic` and was build against the old version and doesn't work with the new version. You will have to fix that (or post the file here).

Comment: yea, now i can get this. I posted that file and can get reason for error, will try to either comment the code or fix accordingly.